# How to connect to Oracle with Perl using LDAP?

Tags: perl, oracle, ldap

I will be needing to connect to an Oracle server on a system that only supports LDAP for name lookup, rather than TNSNAMES.ora. Is this possible with perl? I am quite sure that I can install the Net::LDAP module and parse the connection information myself, but I was looking for a standard way.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to connect to Oracle Internet Directory (OID) which is an LDAP implementation... not an Oracle database directly.  Correct?

If so, Net::LDAP all the way via Perl...

```
my $LSERV  = 'yourldaphost.yourdomain.com';                   
my $BASE_DN = 'cn=*,dc=*,dc=*';  # these * values must be filled in correctly for your LDAP
my $timeout = 10;                # How long to wait (in secs).
my $success; my $message;
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new(
     $LSERV, 
     timeout => $timeout
) or die "! Unable to connect to OID LDAP.";
```

Comment: And could he possibly mean a Sun Directory server, now called an Oracle Directory server too?  (NOt that it really matters to your answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should use whatever is defined in the sqlnet.ora of the client install.  Perl shouldn't have to worry about the naming method.